# Replacing PIPE (|) symbol in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, regexp-replace

Hello i have a text containing pipe (|) symbol and i want to replace it with space. This is the text in the column description

> |TrueCricketLover|M€$$!|
>   PTI|Capricorn|No DM|#TeamIK|@shaneRWatson33 ❤
>   Boom Boom❤
>   Striving to be a better human!

I have tried the regexp_replace function like this

```
regexp_replace(description,'|',' ')
```

This command returns this value

> | T r u e C r i c k e t L o v e r | M € $ $ ! | 
>    P T I | C a p r i c o r n | N o   D M | # T e a m I K | @ s h a n e R W a t s o n 3 3   ❤ 
>    B o o m   B o o m ❤ 
>    S t r i v i n g   t o   b e   a   b e t t e r   h u m a n ! 
>    L o v e   h i m   w h o   l e a s t   D e s e r v e s   I t , T h a t ' s   i t ❤

It is not replacing the pipe (|) symbol. Kindly help.

Comment: Try escaping the pipe character. For example: `regexp_replace(description,'\|',' ')`

Comment: It is returning this value  | T r u e C r i c k e t L o v e r | M € $ $ ! | 
 P T I | C a p r i c o r n | N o   D M | # T e a m I K | @ s h a n e R W a t s o n 3 3   ❤ 
 B o o m   B o o m ❤ 
 S t r i v i n g   t o   b e   a   b e t t e r   h u m a n ! 
 L o v e   h i m   w h o   l e a s t   D e s e r v e s   I t , T h a t ' s   i t ❤

Comment: OK. Try this: `regexp_replace(description,'\\|',' ')`

Comment: Or `translate(description, '|', ' ')`

Comment: regexp_replace(description,'\\|',' ') works perfectly

Answer (score 8):

**Try this:**
select regexp_replace(description,'\\|',' ') from table;

Answer (score 3):

Since a pipe character is an OR operator in regex in must be escaped. In Java flavored regex, two escape characters, back slashes, must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one add \ in your regexp_replace function

insert overwrite table_name select regexp_replace(id,'\\|',' ') from table_name